# Can I send state value with EmailJS?

Tags: reactjs, email, smtp

I am trying to create a simple e-shop shopping cart in React (without payment for now) and I would like the order to be sent to me by email using EmailJS. The content of the order is saved in state `cartItems` but I don't know how to pass it to display in the email. As far as I understand, EmailJS is intended for passing data that is filled in the form but perhaps there is another way?

This is my component EmailOrderForm

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
> import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
> import { useCart } from '../../cart-context';
> 
> const EmailOrderForm = () => {
> const { cartItems } = useCart();
> 
> const form = useRef();
> 
> const sendEmail = (e) => {
> e.preventDefault();
> 
> emailjs
>       .sendForm(
>         'service_xxxxx',
>         'template_xxxxx',
> form.current,
>         'XXxxXXxxXXxxXXxx',
>       )
>       .then(
>         (result) => {
> console.log('SUCCESS!');
>         },
>         (error) => {
> console.log('FAILED!');
>         },
>       );
> console.log(cartItems);
>   };
> 
> return (
>     <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
>       <label>Name</label>
>       <input type="text" name="user_name" />
>       <label>Email</label>
>       <input type="email" name="user_email" />
>       <label>Note</label>
>       <textarea name="message" />
>       <ul name="order">
>         {cartItems.map((item) => (
>           <li className="cart-item" key={item.index}>
>             <div
> className="cart-item-image"
> style={{
> backgroundImage: `url(${item.image})`,
> width: '100px',
> height: '100px',
> backgroundSize: 'cover',
> backgroundPosition: 'center',
>               }}
> alt={item.name}
>             ></div>
>             <span className="cart-item-name">{item.name}</span>
>             <span className="cart-item-price">{item.price}&nbsp;Kč</span>
>           </li>
>         ))}
>       </ul>
>       <button className="cart-order" type="submit">
> Order
>       </button>
>     </form>
>   );
> };
> 
> export default EmailOrderForm;
```